# Excel IF, ELSE, AND

Tags: excel, if-statement

Not sure how to write an excel formula to solve for this.

This is what is in my excel spreadsheet. Transactions are cell A1, 1042 is cell B2. This is supposed to be a sample credit card transaction. It has info for the date of the purchase, merchant, category and value of purchase.

```
 Transaction #   1042           
 Date            2/14/15            
 Merchant        Target         
 Category        Groceries          
 Value           50         
 Points          (solving for this) 

Card 1              
   Date Range:  2/10/15 2/17/15    2/18/15  2/22/15
   Gas                  5                 10    
   Dining               4                  9    
   Target               3                  8    
   BP                   2                  7    
   Everything           1                  6
```

What I am trying to do is say if the date falls
in between (date 1 and date 2), & the merchant name is target, then the value is 50 * 3.

Else if the merchant name is BP, then the value is 2*50.

OR if the category is gas, then the value is 5 * 50

OR if the category is dining, then the value is 4 * 50

OR if its none of the critera, then its 1 * 50.

I would also like to do the same if it falls under the other dates, 3 & 4 and if it does, then compute the reward value for that transaction given it's date.

Also as a bonus, I would want to choose the higher of the two values if the merchant and category both had a match.

I've been messing with the IF function for the last hour and cant seem to get anything figured out, it just sends back "null".

Thanks!

Comment: You will need to you INDEX MATCH function for this. Check this link, hope it helps you :http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/12/13/formula-for-matching-a-date-within-a-date-range-in-excel/

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the data? It's not clear how it is laid out. For example the date ranges under Card 1. Are the dates in separate cells? All in all, this layout is not ideal for formula analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this formula does what you describe, when the data is laid out like in the screenshot. 
    =MAX(B5*MAX(IFERROR(INDEX($B$10:$C$14,MATCH(B3,$A$10:$A$14,0),MATCH(B2,$B$9:$C$9,1)),0),IFERROR(INDEX($B$10:$C$14,MATCH(B4,$A$10:$A$14,0),MATCH(B2,$B$9:$C$9,1)),0)),B5)

[image]

Edit: In the first version I was using named ranges for Merchant and Category. I've changed it back to cell references.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your spreadsheet looks like this:

```
| Transaction # | 1042      |
| Date          | 2/14/15   |
| Merchant      | Target    |
| Category      | Groceries |
| Value         | 50        |
| Points        | (ans1)    | (ans2)    
|               |
| Card 1        |
| Date Range:   | 2/10/15   | 2/17/15  | 2/18/15  | 2/22/15  |
| Gas           | 5         |          | 10       |          |
| Dining        | 4         |          | 9        |          |
| Target        | 3         |          | 8        |          |
| BP            | 2         |          | 7        |          |
| Everything    | 1         |          | 6        |          |
```

Using the VLOOKUP(), you can return the the value in the matching row. so if Target matches, it would return 3. If it's not found it returns #N/A. So using IFERROR(), you can check for this. The following is what i have.
Use this is cell B6 for the first date range:

```
=IF(B2>C9,IF(B2<D9,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B3,A10:E14,2,FALSE),B14),0),0)*B5
```

Use this is cell C6 for the next date range

```
=IF(B2>E9,IF(B2<F9,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B4,A10:E14,4,FALSE),D14),0),0)*B5
```

then just compare the two for the greater value.